# $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}(f(x)\leq g(x) \Rightarrow \sup(f)\leq \sup(g))$. True or false?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be functions, such that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Tell if $\sup(f)\leq \sup(g)$ is true or false. If true, prove it. If false give a counterexample.

Well, $\sup(f)$ stands for the supremum of the range of $f$, the same for $\sup(g)$. The problem is on the extended real number line, so the supremum can be equal to $\infty$.

Can you give me a clue? Thanks

Comment: Your title is different from the body. The equivalent mathematical expression is: $$\left(\forall x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)\leq g(x) \right)\Rightarrow \sup(f)\leq \sup(g)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the title was my mathematic interpretation of the word problem. If $f(x)\leq g(x)$ then $\sup(f)\leq \sup(g)$, for every $x$ in the domain.

Comment: That wasn't what the word problem said.

Comment: The first sentence says:$$\forall x\in \mathbb R:f(x)\leq g(x)$$. From this, you are meant to be able to conclude $\sup(f)\leq \sup(g)$. Note, no $\forall x$ in the second part. The first sentence alone is affected by $\forall x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the convention that $\infty \leq \infty$, then is true. The simple reason is that the supremum is the least upper bound, and that if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x$, then every upper bound for $g$ is an upper bound for $f$.

Comment: I get it, the supremum of $g$ is an upper bound of $f$. And so, by the definition of supremum, $\sup(f) \leq \sup(g)$. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x$, then you must have $f(x) \le \sup_y g(y)$ for all $x$. If this is true, you must have $\sup_z f(z) \le \sup_y g(y)$, which is the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sup f>\sup g$ then $\sup g$ must be finite and some $y\in\mathbb{R}$
must exist with $f\left(y\right)>\sup g\geq g\left(y\right)$. This
contradicts that $f\left(x\right)\leq g\left(x\right)$ for each $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0$ be a value such that $f(x_0) = \sup f$.  By assumption $g(x_0) \geq f(x_0)$.  By property of sup, $\sup g \ge g(x_0)$.  Combine: $\sup g \ge g(x_0) \ge f(x_0) = \sup f$.